# How to make Powershell script to execute git command?

Tags: command-line, bash, powershell, git

Good day!

I'm not familiar with Powershell at all, and I want to make a script that excecutes every night at 2AM a git pull command in a given directory location. So basically the script must "cd" to that location and then execute "git pull".

I know Windows have the scheduler in which you can call the script, I just have no idea how to make that script.

Thanks in advance.

Warm regards.

Answer (score 6):

`cd` in Powershell an alias for `Set-Location` which *is* `cd`, and if the Git command line executable is in your path, you can call it from Powershell as well.

```
cd C:\path\to\myrepo.git\
git pull
```

or

```
Set-Location C:\path\to\myrepo.git\
Git pull
```

The second solution is more idiomatic for Powershell. And remember, if the path to your repo contains spaces, you must put it between quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. One of those 2 options must be saved as .ps1 file and be executed with Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Yes. You just need to be sure that Git is in your path. If you don't know, open a Powershell prompt and type `git --version`.